# Php sort multidimensional array by special criterion

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
$leadsArr = [
        0=>[
            0=>[
                'code'=>'Code1',
                'percentage'=>'',
            ] ,
            1=>[
                'code'=>'Code1',
                'percentage'=>''
            ]
        ],

        1=>[
            0=>[
                'code'=>'Code2',
                'percentage'=>'',
            ] ,
            1=>[
                'code'=>'Code2',
                'percentage'=>''
            ] ,
            2=>[
                'code'=>'Code2',
                'percentage'=>''
            ]
        ],

        3=>[
            0=>[
                'code'=>'Code3',
                'percentage'=>'25',
            ] ,
            1=>[
                'code'=>'Code3',
                'percentage'=>''
            ] ,
        ]
    ];
```

I need sort this array by the highest number of empty 'percentage' value.
So the result must be 1,0,2 (array indexes).
Please help me, how can i do it? Thanks

Comment: There is no 2...

Comment: What have you tried so far for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uasort` for achieving your requirements. Try this-

```
uasort($leadsArr, function($a, $b) {
    $countA = 0;
    $countB = 0;

    foreach ($a as $v)
    {
        if ($v['percentage'] === '') $countA++;
    }

    foreach ($b as $v)
    {
        if ($v['percentage'] === '') $countB++;
    }

    return $countB - $countA;
});
```

Alternatively, you can also gain the result by using `array_filter` instead of `foreach`.

```
uasort($leadsArr, function($a, $b) {
    $countA = 0;
    $countB = 0;

    $countA = count(array_filter($a, function($x) {
        return $x['percentage'] === '';
    }));

    $countB = count(array_filter($b, function($x) {
        return $x['percentage'] === '';
    }));

    return $countB - $countA;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can i keep array keys?

Comment: Ok, think need use uasort